# Flutter showTimePicker with specific 15 minute intervals

Tags: datetime, flutter, datetimepicker

For the **showTimePicker** function in Flutter used to select a time, is it possible to set a defined time interval (such as 15 minutes) to prevent users from selecting any other timing?

Currently, this is the code I have for creating a default TimePicker.

```
showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way in the API, I have raised this issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60573

Answer (score 5):

You could try using this temporal solution using: [time_picker_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/time_picker_widget)

[image]

Copy the following code into this [DEMO](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5c32e473c8c1c9687966453d0dcf42de?)

```dart
showCustomTimePicker(
    context: context,
    // It is a must if you provide selectableTimePredicate
    onFailValidation: (context) =>
        showMessage(context, 'Unavailable selection.'),
    initialTime: TimeOfDay(
        hour: _availableHours.first,
        minute: 0),
    selectableTimePredicate: (time) =>
        _availableHours.indexOf(time.hour) != -1 &&
        time.minute % 15 == 0).then(
    (time) =>
        setState(() => selectedTime = time?.format(context))),
```